# How can I import a large (multi-GB) sql file into postgres using dotnet core?

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

My database needs to mirror another, to which I have no access except for a nightly export of the sql file. I could script the import using psql.exe, but would prefer everything to be under the control of the dotnet core application.

I can't use the COPY command, because the file contains ALL the sql to set up the schemas and tables, as well as all the sql commands to insert/alter/copy the data.

I can't use `\i` because that is a postgresql console command, not something I can run through npgsql.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is it inherently a bad idea, and should I run a script to import it outside of the dotnet application? Should the dotnet application run and talk to the psql.exe program directly?

Comment: I haven't tried this so what I am saying is purely on a concept level but you could use a streamer, read the file in small chunks and filter - process only what's usefull to you (eg only the copy commands). That being said i get the feeling you are trying to put too many responsibilites on that dotnet core application (i'm guilty of that myself tbh). Can you provide some basic info as to what the purpose of the dotnet core application is?

Comment: @Convel that sounds like it would require parsing SQL, which generally isn't a feasible thing.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Yeah I guess it's safe to assume that a multi-GB sql file won't be easy to parse (most probably there will be to many individual edge cases to cover). Thnx for the inside.

Comment: I'd highly recommend avoiding parsing SQL regardless of the file size.

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically parse the SQL file in .NET and send it to PostgreSQL, but this is a very non-trivial thing to do, since you'd need to understand where statements end (identify semicolons) in order to send chunks.

You could, of course, send the entire file as a single chunk, but if it's huge, that may be a bad idea.

At the end of the day, I don't think there's any particular issue with launching psql.exe as an external process from .NET, and properly inspecting its exit code for error handling. Any reason you think you need to avoid that?

Comment: It didn't seem like a good idea to be calling local executables. Is this considered good practice?

Comment: It certainly seems better than to reimplement something complex which an external program already does well. And as long as the program just does its thing and you properly handle its exit codes etc., any reason to avoid that?